# Creating an if-statement without hard-coding

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have an array that I want to check, for example:

```
 var str = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
```

but I want check if this array's string values are in a database or of some sort. **I want to find out which one matches and store the found matches inside an array.**

```
 var dataFound = [];
 var count = 0;
 for(var stringData in someDatabase){
    if(stringData == str[0] || stringData == str[1] ...etc){
         dataFound[count] = stringData;
         count++;
    }
 }

 //someDatabase will consist of strings like random alphabets 
 from a-z
```

I don't want to hardcode the if-statement because a query array can be anywhere from a, b, c .. (n) as n can represent any amount of strings. I tried to use a for-loop from 0 to **str.length** but that can take quite a while when I can use **or** operator to search in one go with all the string values, is there a way around this?

Comment: look for array#includes or array#indexOf or array#find ... and many other methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: You can `break` from your loop just like `||` shortcuts when it found something, so that it won't take a while.

Comment: I don't want to break though, I want to find all possible values by using the | | operator and return the ones that have been found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (str.indexOf(stringData) > -1) {
    //found
}
```

> [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (MDN)

Comment: For some reason, I even tried this in console in Chrome but it's only returning the actual index found of the array instead of returning either 0 or -1 when found

Comment: `str.indexOf("c")` will return `2` because `"c"` is the third element in the array (zero-based so the third item is located at index `2`), whereas `str.indexOf("c") > -1` will return `true` because we're asking "does `"c"` exist in `str`?"

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If str is an array, can you do this?

```
var dataFound = [];
var count = 0;
for(var stringData in someDatabase){
 for (i++; i < str.length; i++) {
  if(stringData == str[i]){
     dataFound[count] = stringData;
     count++;
  }
 }
```

}

Comment: I can do that but that's going to take (n)th time to search for where as I can use or operator **||** for each str value to be found in the database so it will only iterate once since we're looking for several values at once for each array in someDatabase